# ExecuteBatch is not executing just once, but after every record. Why?

Tags: java, sql, sqlite

Here is my code:

```
    prodsQuery = dbc
                .connect()
                .prepareStatement(
                        "INSERT INTO 'duplicates' (C_ContactID, C_EmailAddress, 
C_DataSourceID, C_DateCreated)"
                                + "VALUES (?,?,?,?);");
        // for (Record x : records) {

        for (int i = startAtRecord; i <= records.size(); i++) {
            prodsQuery.setInt(1, records.get(i).getContactID());
            prodsQuery.setString(2, records.get(i).getEmail());
            prodsQuery.setString(3, records.get(i).getDataSourceID());
            prodsQuery.setString(4, records.get(i).getDateCreated());

            // addBatch is better than executeUpdate or executeQuery in this
            // case
            prodsQuery.addBatch();
            // save number of record in case of failure
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(
                    "data\\resumerecord.txt"));
            out.write(i + "\n");
            out.close();
            // execute batch every some records, in case of failure to start
            // at some point
            if (i % 5000 == 0) {
                prodsQuery.executeBatch();
                System.out.println("Batch was executed.");

            }

        }
        prodsQuery.executeBatch();
        prodsQuery.close();
```

I want to be effective thats why I would like to execute batch every 5000 records. But while I was testing and accidentally I turned off the program, then looked into DB and found that it stopped at record 7589. That means it is adding records one by one.

Why?

Shouldn't it insert whole chunks inside?

I thought that is the reason why batch is more effective.

Isn't there any other way how to store the ID of the record where it finished inserting? Maybe read it from db when program starts.

Comment: If you turned off the program, the transaction should never have committed. You *are* running this within a transaction?

Comment: Make sure your connection has auto commit set to false and add a connection rollback to your exception handler

Comment: How to do this? Give me an answer,  I will mark it answered. Btw, i did not do anything with auto commiting, if it is true by default then it is true and I must find a way how to change it to false, or you might answer it for me, thanks.

Comment: I did this: `conn.setAutoCommit(false);` and now there is nothing in the DB at all.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you are in autocommit mode, each individual INSERT statement will have its own automatic transaction.
This also applies to the statements executed by `executeBatch`; that function will *not* create a single transaction for you.

Committing a transaction is the most time-consuming part of this program, so it's likely that aborting the program will happen somewhere in the middle of `executeBatch`'s loop.

To reduce the transaction overhead, disable autocommit mode, and manually call `commit` on the connection.

Comment: Thanks, but now it writes me this:
[SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (cannot VACUUM from within a transaction) dont you know why?

Comment: There is no VACUUM in the code you've shown. You should not disable autocommit for other code.

Answer (score 1):

You should execute the `batch insert` inside a `transaction`. When executed inside a transaction you can make sure that either all updates are executed, or none are updated.

You should always run SQL query with auto-commit mode disabled even with `JDBC Batch insert and update` and do `commit()` explicitly.

something like this

```
try{
    connection.setAutoCommit(false);
    // add to batch and execute batch
    connection.commit();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
finally{
//closing statements
   }
```